# pecl installing extension on production server troubles

Tags: php, production-environment, pecl

So I installed the pecl oauth module locally, and it all works perfectly.  I then tried to do this for the production server but ran into some problems.

If I say sudo pecl install oauth, I get this error:

```
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/oauth"
install failed
```

So I figure I have to update pecl.php.net, so I try the command `sudo pecl channel-update pecl.php.net`, but then I get this output:

```
Updating channel "pecl.php.net"
Channel "pecl.php.net" is not responding over http://, failed with message:
Connection to 'pecl.php.net:80' failed: Connection refused
Trying channel "pecl.php.net" over https:// instead
Cannot retrieve channel.xml for channel "pecl.php.net" (Connection to `pecl.php.net:443' failed: Connection refused)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a firewall blocking outgoing connections from your server?  What does pecl.php.net resolve to if you try to ping it?

Comment: No response, should I set up a proxy?

Comment: That's strange, can you get out to other hosts?  What happens if you try `lynx www.google.com` assuming lynx is installed or `telnet www.google.com 80`?  I just wonder if all connections on port 80 are blocked, or you are having problems with this specific host.

Comment: Connection rejected to google or yahoo.  I did some yum installs that worked, but I don't know if yum gets those from external servers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, I figured out a way around it.  You set up a proxy, but not the normal export http_proxy: way.  Here's the command:

```
sudo pear config-set http_proxy http://username:password@yourproxy:yourport
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Googled a long time for this. <3

Comment: Stackoverflow saves our lives as always. <3