# Installing Xdebug for MAMP with pecl

Tags: installation, xdebug, pecl

At http://xdebug.org/docs/install I read:

```
Installing with PEAR/PECL is as easy as:

# pecl install xdebug
```

When I try this, I get errors:

```
$ pecl install xdebug
bash: pecl: command not found
```

Trying again, from the folder that contains pecl:

```
cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/
bash-3.2$ ./pecl install xdebug
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/xdebug"
install failed
```

However visiting [pecl.php.net/xdebug](http://pecl.php.net/xdebug) redirects to http://pecl.php.net/package/xdebug, which indicates that the package clearly exists.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 5):

Try running the following command,

pecl channel-update pecl.php.net

Comment: this did it for me on linux mint, you might consider running it as sudo though.

Answer (score 1):

To get it working what I did was manually compile and install the debug extension with the following commands:

```
wget http://xdebug.org/files/xdebug-x.x.x.tgz
tar -xzvf xdebug-x.x.x.tgz
cd xdebug-x.x.x
phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

Comment: Does it matter where you install this? Any ideal location?

Answer (score 1):

#### Installing as root may fix it

I got the same error message when trying to install Xdebug via PECL. When I tried to follow [user1310789’s advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33411797) to update the channel, I got the same error message as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165400/pecl-installing-extension-on-production-server-troubles):

```
Updating channel "pecl.php.net"
Channel "pecl.php.net" is not responding over http://, failed with message:
Connection to 'pecl.php.net:80' failed: Connection refused
Trying channel "pecl.php.net" over https:// instead
Cannot retrieve channel.xml for channel "pecl.php.net" (Connection to `pecl.php.net:443' failed: Connection refused)
```

The accepted answer to that question indirectly held the answer. I didn’t have to create a proxy, but I noticed the `pear` command in the answer was run as root.

I tried updating the PEAR and PECL channels using `sudo` – and voilà, it worked immediately. Installing Xdebug still failed with the same error, but `sudo`ing it again fixed it.

*Why* PEAR and PECL appear to suddenly require being run as root to function I have no idea. It feels quite iffy, running a remote, online installer with root access. But it was apparently what was needed in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Installed on Mac, not MAMP though

```
brew install php
sudo pecl install xdebug
```